# Apache server config redirect from IP to domain name EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

I am running an apache webserver on a linux EC2 instance.

The problem is that you can access the server using the IP address, DNS and the domain name. This causes a problem for SEO and I want to tidy it up.

I have read on the apache documentation that you can do a mod_rewrite and this needs to be done in the httpd.conf if you have root access otherwise in the .htaccess for per directory override. 
I have root access so I am trying to change the  httpd.conf

If the user types in 
http://52.17.12.123/
or
http://ec2-52.17.12.123.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

I want them to be redirected to 
www.example.com

This is what I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/my-website"
 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^52.17.12.123.com$
 RewriteRule /* http://www.example.com/ [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems to partially work but www.example.com does not load due to to many redirects.

Comment: or use security groups to restrict what IPs can reach that server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^52.17.12.123.com$` means that the `RewriteRule` is applied whenever the hostname is not `52.17.12.123.com`.

However, your goal is to redirect whenever the host is not your own hostname. Therefore you need to use this configuration for rewrites instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R=301]
```

This should accomplish your goal, and prevents the rewrite look for `www.example.com`.

I also added `=301` to the rewrite rule, so that Apache will send `301 Moved Permanently` redirect instead of `302` status code to the browser, which is the recommended way for doing SEO redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^52\.17\.12\.123$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ec2-52\.17\.12\.123\.eu-west-1\.compute\.amazonaws\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In these cases it is best to use "if host does nost match X, redirect" approach.

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen You are right...By the way i just wanted to translate the OP `if..or...` But for sure it was not the most improved approach ;)